# Callback URL not working while setting up a facebook messenger bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger

I am trying to make a facebook messenger bot, I am using c9.io as my remote server 
for node.js app and used this code from this repo: https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/tree/master/node

My app.js looks good running:
Debugger listening on port 15454
Node app is running on port 8080

But I have one problem when trying to create webhook:

This is the message I get:

> The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge,
>   expected value = '561638383', received='

I am giving 'https://facebook-bot2-lulzimfazlija.c9users.io' as Callback URL, but for some reason it shows the error above.

Anyone knows what is the issue here?

Comment: What facebook expects when it validates your url, is not being returned in your call.

Comment: Here is a working bot example: https://github.com/d-pollard/koa-facebook-messenger-echo-bot

Comment: @You, could you explain in more details what does facebook expects from me?

Comment: In that instance, they expected to see: 561638383

Comment: @You what does this mean? Does this mean I should add this value somewhere in my code? for ex in "validationToken": "lulzimfazlija123", I should change it to 561638383 ?? I dont really understand, if u dont mind to explain this in more details.. thn x

Comment: it worked, after I changed the callback url to : 'https://facebook-bot2-lulzimfazlija.c9users.io/webhook', and idk why!